# Nan values in training epochs of siamese network

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, siamese-network

the loss function is giving output as nan while training the model. I wanted to compare two pics of the same person.
ive used an online dataset for training facial data
while predicting its gives this error.
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_17" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 128, 128, 3), found shape=(None, 135, 3)

```
# Define the Siamese network architecture
def create_siamese_network(input_shape):
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    return model

# Define the contrastive loss function
def contrastive_loss(y_true, y_pred, margin=1):
    return tf.reduce_mean(y_true * tf.square(y_pred) + (1 - y_true) * tf.square(tf.maximum(margin - y_pred, 0)))

# Load and preprocess the dataset (assuming you have already collected and preprocessed the data)

# Split the dataset into training and validation sets
train_images_a, train_images_b = train_images[:800], train_images[800:1600]
# Create the labels for the training set
train_labels = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(800,))
train_labels = tf.cast(train_labels, tf.float32)
# Split the dataset into validation and test sets
val_images_a, val_images_b = train_images[1600:1800], train_images[1800:2000]
test_images_a, test_images_b = train_images[2000:2200], train_images[2200:2400]
# Create the labels for the validation and test sets
val_labels = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(200,))
val_labels = tf.cast(val_labels, tf.float32)
test_labels = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(200,))
test_labels = tf.cast(test_labels, tf.float32)
# Normalize the images

train_images_a, train_images_b = train_images_a / 255.0, train_images_b / 255.0
val_images_a, val_images_b = val_images_a / 255.0, val_images_b / 255.0
test_images_a, test_images_b = test_images_a / 255.0, test_images_b / 255.0
input_shape = (128, 128, 3)
siamese_network = create_siamese_network(input_shape)

# Define the two input branches for the Siamese network
input_a = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
input_b = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
output_a = siamese_network(input_a)
output_b = siamese_network(input_b)

# Define the distance metric between the outputs of the two branches
distance = layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.norm(x[0] - x[1], axis=1, keepdims=True))([output_a, output_b])

# Define the Siamese model
siamese_model = models.Model(inputs=[input_a, input_b], outputs=distance)

# Compile the Siamese model
siamese_model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(0.001,clipnorm=1.), loss=contrastive_loss)
# split the dataset into training and validation sets
train_images_a, train_images_b, train_labels = train_images[:800], train_images[800:1600], train_labels[:800]
# Train the Siamese model
epochs = 10
batch_size = 32
siamese_model.fit([train_images_a, train_images_b], train_labels, 
                  batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_data=([val_images_a, val_images_b], val_labels))
```

I've tried casting the labels in Float32 and used clipnorm=1. as solved in a solution. but it didn't work. I get large values like 7023 before it goes to Nan.